# anyone know of a list of spells for the arcane archer's imbue spell ability

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I am looking for a list that match the arcane archer's imbue spell ability.   Please help save my 60 year old eyes, LOL.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  As currently asked, this question is basically "can I have a list of every spell in the game with an area," which is likely to be too broad to be a good fit for this site's format.  It might be [better suited to a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), or you might be able to edit this question to be a better fit for our Q&A format (e.g., by specifying the kinds of things you want to *do* with Imbue Arrow).

Comment: Another possibly-useful way to narrow the question might be to focus on the special property of imbue arrow: namely the ability to put spell effects *over there* that ordinarily you could only cast around yourself.

Comment: I had an answer but it went to on hold...

Comment: [Related meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7638/23970) on questions that are asking for large lists of spells that fit a criterion and whether they're on- or 0ff-topic. In fact, I'm going to ask that reopen voters make their case on meta rather than here; given a collection of existing closed questions of this form, if this is to be open it seems to me that needs to be hashed out as a site-wide understanding.

Answer (score -1):

> **Imbue Arrow (Su)**
>
> At 2nd level, an arcane archer gains the ability to place an **area spell** upon an arrow. When the arrow is fired, the spell’s area is centered where the arrow lands, even if the spell could normally be centered only on the caster. This ability allows the archer to use the bow’s range rather than the spell’s range. **A spell cast in this way uses its standard casting time and the arcane archer can fire the arrow as part of the casting.** The arrow must be fired during the round that the casting is completed or the spell is wasted. If the arrow misses, the spell is wasted.

Essentially, *Imbue Arrow* allows you to use the range of your bow as the range of the spell by making a normal ranged attack. Any spell that effects more than one target is fair game, so long as you have the spell prepared as normal (Firebolt would not be an example, Fireball would).

So any spell you have that affects more than one target, is currently prepared, and you have line of sight to for a bow attack is fair game.

Comment: This isn’t what was asked. The question isn’t confused about the rules; the question is seeking a convenient list of spells that meet the criteria, to save having to dig through hundreds of spells to find which ones are valid.

Comment: @KRyan In my post, I pointed out that any spell that effects an area can be used with Imbue Spell. It didn't seem useful to type out literally every area spell in the game and call it even.

Comment: Yes, that’s why the question has been closed for being too broad: what was asked for was not a reasonable thing to provide. That doesn’t change what the question is, or an answer’s responsibility to address that question.